# How to add click event tot button in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$.ajax({
  url:'/getArticles',
  method:'GET',
 }).done(function(articles){
  var content = '';
  articles.forEach(function(e){
   var res = "<div class='article'>" + 
      "<h3>" + e.title +  "</h3>" + 
      "<p>" + e.content + "</p><br>" + 
      "<button onclick=crud.remove(" + e._id + ")>Remove</button><br>" + 
       "</div>";
   content += res;
  });
  $('#allarticles').append(content);
 });
 window.crud = (function(){
  // Remove an article
  function remove(id){
   console.log(id);
  }
```

How do I insert `e._id` correctly here so it will put id of article?

When I click this button it says:

> (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Put the parameter in quotes: `"<button onclick=\"crud.remove('" + e._id + '")\">Remove</button><br>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in your button creation using jQuery. You missed single quotes for id. Also you were missing some braces.

```
<button onclick=crud.remove(" + e._id + ")>Remove</button><br>
```

Replace your above line with this

```
<button onclick=crud.remove('" + e._id + "')>Remove</button><br>
```

I have corrected your code :

```js
$.ajax({
  url : '/getArticles',
  method : 'GET',
 }).done(
   function(articles) {
    var content = '';
    articles.forEach(function(e) {
     var res = "<div class='article'>" + "<h3>" + e.title
       + "</h3>" + "<p>" + e.content + "</p><br>"
       + "<button onclick=crud.remove('" + e._id
       + "')>Remove</button><br>" + "</div>";
     content += res;
    });
    $('#allarticles').append(content);
   });
 window.crud = (function() {
  // Remove an article
  function remove(id) {
   console.log(id);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```